# What is the pythonic way to get file handles from the command line with relative or absolute paths?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I write a command line script in python, I'm assuming that it can be invoked from anywhere. This seems to cause incongruity when I want to pass a list of files into the script.

Passing the files using a list or wildcard arguments (whether expanded by bash under *nix or glob.glob with Windows) will return either a relative path or an absolute one, depending on how the file path was described, but this seems to give two different behaviors which have to either be checked or harmonized.

If the script is in the same directory as the files to be imported, this isn't really a problem, but if the script is in a different directory, it seems like you need to grab the absolute path first:

```
import os,sys,glob

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    file_list = glob.glob(arg)
    for fn in file_list:
        print("File Reference: {}".format(os.path.abspath(fn)))
```

---

```
> pwd
/Users/user1/Desktop/script_dir/

> cd ~/Desktop

> script_dir/test.py test_dir/*.csv /Users/user1/Desktop/test_dir/*.txt

File Reference: /Users/user1/Desktop/test_dir/temp1.csv
File Reference: /Users/user1/Desktop/test_dir/temp2.csv
File Reference: /Users/user1/Desktop/test_dir/temp1.txt
File Reference: /Users/user1/Desktop/test_dir/temp2.txt
```

Assuming the program continued on to do something with the files, it would then manipulate them by absolute path. Is this the correct thing to do here? It seems weirdly klugy, and I can seem to find any references that lay this out.

Comment: You can use `pathlib.Path.cwd()` to get the current working directory that the script was invoked from, if that's helpful. I would just suggest to use `pathlib.Path` and it should know whether the path laid out is absolute or relative for you, IIRC.

Comment: I'm not sure how that fixes the problem though. In some sense, I don't care where the script is, I only care that it's manipulating files in the directory that the user is currently in. Maybe I should clarify this in the example code.

Comment: Note that I edited my comment. Anyways, I don't understand the actual problem here; if you specify an absolute path, it uses one, if you specify a relative path, it uses that. You can still traverse relative paths and absolute paths however you need to, and you don't have to special case it---Python will work with both. Do you just want to be able to like log the absolute path everytime? Then just `abspath` it before you write it. I think we need an MCVE of the actual problem here, if there is one.

Comment: "In some sense, I don't care where the script is, I only care that it's manipulating files in the directory that the user is currently in." that's what the current working directory *is*, it isn't the path that the script is in, it's equivalent to checking `cwd` in terminal. Python uses the current working directory by default for relative paths.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. Just use the paths that the user supplied. The OS automatically interprets relative paths properly.

Comment: You would only need to convert to absolute paths if you need to save the paths and use them later, from a process that might be in a different directory.